# Facebook OAuth Dialog only works on the second time

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-oauth

I'm building an android app with phonegap that use Facebook authentication.  The problem is that when I first click the log-in button, the log-in box appear but after I sign-in, the OAuth Dialog just show "the page you requested was not found". I have to press "back" button and click the log-in button again then the OAuth Dialog appear everything else is fine. Anyone know what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here on iOS. First time showing the OAuth Dialog in an WebView generates this error parameter `error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.` in the url. This error is not visible to the user. After the user enter his email/password and tap on Login a new page with the error _the page you requested was not found_ is shown. Showing the OAuth Dialog a second time will work. [I think this is the same problem](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12331889/page-cannot-be-found-error-on-facebook-login-on-my-wp-and-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on iOS and found a workaround. Our facebook app was configured as **Mobile Web**. We have changed it to **Website with Facebook Login** (in the basic settings). We also enabled the **October 2012 Breaking Changes** and **Events Timezone** in the advanced settings.

Comment: Just a little more.  What url should I put in "Website with Facebook Login" because I'm doing an app. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have a server which handles the facebook registration you don't need this. Just try the second part of my answer. Hope this helps.